# Unable to show current location on google map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

I am working on app which show my current location on google map.I have tried hard but i am not able to show my current location on google map.
Below is my code.
'

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public void initGamp(View root) {

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        // check if map is created successfully or not


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        initGamp(rootView);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
//        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
//        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
//        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Log.i("MAP","BEFORE LOCATION");
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        Log.i("MAP", "AFTER LOCATION");
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);

        Log.i("MAP", "END LOCATION");



    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Log.i("MAP","CHANGE LOCATION");

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));


    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

**Permissions in manifest**

```
<!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

I have checked the gps of app is on but still it does not show current location

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code on a device, and I was able to see the current location **AFTER** moving around for a little (*I think the code triggered `onLocationChanged`*). It showed the blue current location marker, which verifies that your code for the `Maps` works fine **IF** triggered properly.

About the code you posted, noticed that you're calling `return;` after this `if statement`:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

-- this makes the code below it, unreachable. I think that is a factor as to why the current location doesn't show up for some reason. After modifying it (*removed `return;`*), I was able to proceed with the code below it:

```
Log.i(""MAP"",""BEFORE LOCATION"");
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        Log.i(""MAP"", ""AFTER LOCATION"");
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);

        Log.i(""MAP"", ""END LOCATION"");
```

-- here, I just added a `Log` to see what the value of location is which turns out to be **`null`** (*tested it first using an emulator*). I think this causes the map to NOT show a current location marker. The only permissions I added in my manifest were `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

> PS: After I removed the `return;` in your `if statement`, I got an error that was related with the permissions. What I did was follow the fastest way from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32084038/4625829) (*I just modified my targetSdkVersion to 22*).

Decided to test it out in a device from here on. At first, the map was able to load but did NOT show any current location marker, it just showed the ***locate me*** button in the upper right corner of the map, I also added a `Toast` to show the value of location, which still shows as `null`. Then I went and move around for sometime and that's when the ***map camera directed and zoomed in towards my current location***.

> **During testing on both emulator and device, Location was turned on. :)**

So I think the main concern for you here is **NOT** *not being able to show current location on maps* but *unable to pass the correct data where maps should direct*. I looked around for a while and seen some examples that are quite similar to your code, they just have a few more included in it. The **sample project** mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22519949/4625829) is a good example on how to use `Location` (*the answer itself is useful*).

Hope this helps. Good luck.